# Why is application launcher not changed in game space?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-launcher

App launcher is okay outside of gamespace but doesn't show in gamespace

[image]

Comment: Check all your mipmap and drawable folders. Did you replace your app logo for each variant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just delete the whole "mipmap" package and then right click on "res" folder -> new -> Image Asset -> add your image and press Finish